# Javascript page redirect from Ajax script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Due to some unforeseen reason, I cannot use a *.php extension for my page. And I need to put conditional redirection in the page.

I plan to use *.html, and javascript/Ajax to call a PHP which evaluates the condition
and accordingly sends back a redirection command.

The condition is being evaluated, but how can I give a redirection command from this internal PHP is not clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can actually map all your .html files to .php using .htaccess.**

If that doesn't work for you, your logic should be as follows:

PHP:

```
echo json_encode(array("redirect_url" => $url));
```

Javascript with jQuery (assuming you require AJAX to redirect):

```
$.getJSON("PHP/Controller/Url", function(data) {
    window.location.href = data.redirect_url;
});
```

Javascript (if you simply serve a static html file)

```
<script>
window.location.href = "redirect_url";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.location = "http://new-url"
```

or

```
window.location.href = "http://new-url"
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS,

```
location.assign("http://www.google.com")
```

will redirect your current frame to Google.

So don't send redirect header in PHP, send "flags" in response body and use JS to redirect.